# Can't create a pandas series from numpy array

Tags: python, pandas

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-24949215fb6c> in <module>()
----> 1 s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You should post code rather than snapshot.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reminder I have edited the question.

Comment: Share the full traceback please, not only the final line. This is probably because you assigned an integer to a function. Restart your kernel and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have shared the full traceback.

Comment: What do `print(type(pd.Series))` and `print(type(np.random.randn))` return?

Comment: <class 'int'> & <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

Comment: You assigned an integer value to the Series constructor (`pd.Series`). Like I said, restart your kernel and it will resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So considering there isn't too much information, I'll take a stab at the fact you have possibly used the name of Series and already given it the data type of Integer... Restart your interpreter or tell us the type of Series... Make sure you are not assigning an integer to Series.

Answer (score -1):

its working very well on machine. Ran below lines

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(s)
```

out put is

```
a    1.417221
b    0.172925
c    0.939383
d    0.288705
e    0.128609
dtype: float64

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There is no error in the code. I guess error could be the way you run the code, please check it and mark this as answer or vote if this is helpful

Comment: I didn't down vote it... I don't even have enough reputation to do so.